# Set Up Partition after Dual Boot Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Window 7

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2, dual-boot, partitioning

So here it's, I had downloaded Wubi.exe, and install and run it successfully. The Problem is, when I restart my Laptop, the system showed up a secure boot menu (to choose between Win7 or Ubuntu), after I click into Ubuntu, the system did not demand me to set up any Partition...

So, I am kind of messed up now, I don't know what is the Limit Disk Space for Ubuntu and Windows 7. How do I set up partition after I dual boot it

Please help me, kindly reply to me ASAP... Thanks!

Comment: Usually, you partition the disk first, then install the operating-system, and then finally dual-boot. I'm confused when you say you want to set up partition after dual-booting? Or by "dual-boot", you mean to say that you booted from a Live-CD instead of the hard-drive ?

Answer (score 1):

Installing using Wubi, is just like installing any windows application, so no partitioning is done.

Wubi allows you to install Ubuntu easily in the same fashion you’d use to install any other software program in Windows. It doesn't require the creating of another partition.

If you want to install Ubuntu in its own partition, then you'd uninstall it, just like a windows program, and then download Ubuntu, put it on a DVD or USB flash drive, and follow the instructions described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

Comment: Ok, is it bad to use Wubi?

Comment: Not necessarily.  It depends on your specific situation.  Have a [look](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=481219) at this, it will shed some light on Wubi.

Answer (score 0):

Your mention of Secure Boot makes me think you're running a UEFI system. The last I heard, WUBI was incompatible with UEFI. Thus, if I'm correct, you should remove any files created by your attempt to set up WUBI and begin again with a standard dual-boot configuration.

Comment: Doesn't that solved the secure boot problem? my problem is I scare the space is not enough for Windows later on.